Laplace Transform of Hitting Time of Brownian Motion with Negative Drift
Let $$X_t = X_0 + \mu t + \sigma W_t$$ where $W_t$ is a standard brownian motion, $\mu \in \mathbb{R}$ and $\sigma > 0 $. Let $\tau$ denote the first time of hitting an upward barrier, e.g.:
$$
\tau = \min\{t \geq 0: X_t = U\}
$$
with $U > X_0$. I am tasked with finding:
$$
\mathbb{E}[e^{-\lambda \tau}]
 $$
with $\lambda > 0$.
My approach was to use the martingale:
$$
Z_t = e^{\sqrt{2\lambda} W_{t\wedge \tau} - \lambda t\wedge \tau} 
$$
This simplifies to:
$$
Z_t = e^{{\sqrt{2}\lambda} \left(\frac{X_{t\wedge \tau} - X_0 - \mu{t\wedge \tau}}{\sigma} - \lambda t \wedge \tau\right)}
$$
If $|Z_t|$ was dominated by an integrable random variable (or just bounded)I could use DCT/optional stopping to conclude:
$$
\mathbb{E}[Z_\tau] = Z_0
$$
This would allow me to solve for the expectation rather easily.
However, if $\mu$ is negative, I can't find any way to pass to the limit/apply the optional stopping, as any crude bounds on $Z_t$ are not necessarily integrable. They require something like:
$$
\mathbb{E}[e^{-\mu \tau}]
$$
which when $\mu <0$ could be infinite.
Does anyone have any suggestions? I tried to use Girsanov's theorem but there seem to be some technicalities with $\tau$ and the fact that Girsanov's theorem only applies on finite intervals $[0,T]$. An answer with Girsanov's theorem would be excellent as well. Thanks!

It's to be expected that the case $\mu<0$ is a little trickier, as in that case you have $\Bbb P[\tau<\infty] <1$.
(To keep it simple I'm going to assume $X_0=0$ and $\sigma=1$.)
To compute $\Bbb E[ e^{-\lambda\tau}]$ for $\lambda>0$ a better choice for $Z$ would be
$$
\exp(\alpha W_{t\wedge\tau}-\beta(t\wedge\tau)),
$$
where $\beta = \alpha^2/2$,  and $\alpha>0$ is chosen so that $\alpha\mu+\beta =\lambda$; namely, $\alpha =-\mu+\sqrt{\mu^2+2\lambda}>0$.
Then $1=\Bbb E[Z_t]$ can be written
$$
\eqalign{
1&=\Bbb E\left[e^{\alpha(U-\mu\tau)-\beta\tau}; \tau\le t\right]
+\Bbb E\left[ e^{\alpha(X_t-\mu t)-\beta t}; \tau>t\right]\cr
&=e^{\alpha U}\Bbb E\left[e^{-\lambda\tau}; \tau\le t\right]
+\Bbb E\left[ e^{\alpha X_t-\lambda t}; \tau>t\right].\cr
}
$$
Now let $t\to\infty$. Use monotone convergence on the first term on the right . For the second term notice that $\alpha X_t\le \alpha U$ on the event $\{t<\tau\}$, so that second term is at most $e^{\alpha U-\lambda t}$.
You'll end up with an explicit expression for $\Bbb E\left[e^{-\lambda\tau}; \tau<\infty\right]$.
